# Why do I keep forgetting the physics I've learned?

Tags: soft-question, education, perception

I've taken quite a few physics classes over the years and I read about physics when I can. However, I always forget what I've learned. When someone talks about a concept, until I go review briefly what I learned, it's hard to remember things. How can I improve my ability to hold on to physics knowledge?

Comment: Maybe the Psychology types on [psychology.se] might be worth asking for the particulars of how to get things from short term memory to long term memory best.

Comment: Friendly reminder that comments are for improving the question, not for posting brief answers.

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then, go back to the problems you solved in college and do them again. Redo them in new ways, if possible. If you've forgotten the formulas, take some time to refresh them in your memory. There is nothing wrong with forgetting stuff you've learned; it's normal.

Additionally, there are websites like [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org) that package Physics problems into neat puzzles that entertain you while making you revise different concepts. The key to mastery is repetition.